# xdriinfo says Screen 0: not direct rendering capable

Tags: xorg, 18.04, intel-graphics, mesa

When I give `xdriinfo` command to check the driver associated with my laptop screen, I'm getting the following response although I have Intel HD Graphics 5500

```
Screen 0: not direct rendering capable.
```

output for `sudo lshw -C display` command

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 5500
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:50 memory:a9000000-a9ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:49 memory:aa000000-aaffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:ab000000-ab07ffff*
```

output for `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"` cmd

```
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.0-rc5
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

**Note:** I've Ubuntu 16.04 LTS running in the same laptop where I can get the following result for `xdriinfo` command

```
Screen 0: i965
```

Any kind of help is appreciated!